# Encrypted Password doesn't match at login from firebase database using AES algorithm

Tags: android, firebase, encryption, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to register a new user. At the time of the registration I encrypted the password in the Firebase Database using AES.The Algorithm.password encryption is succesfully. But when I am trying to login the user with the email id and the password, the passwords which I entered in 
the registration form are not matching. Instead the password matches with the encryption string which is stored in the firebase database.

**Register Activity**

```
  public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
  View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MAGIC";
    Firebase mref= null;
    private User user;
    private EditText name;
    private EditText phoneNumber;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private EditText address;
    private Button register;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_username);
    phoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_phone_number);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_new_email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_new_password);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_address);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_register);

    register.setOnClickListener(this);
}
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

    //This method sets up a new User by fetching the user entered details.
    protected void setUpUser() {
    user = new User();
    user.setName(name.getText().toString().trim());
    user.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber.getText().toString().trim());
    user.setAddress(address.getText().toString().trim());
    user.setEmail(email.getText().toString().trim());
    user.setPassword(password.getText().toString().trim());

}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    encryption(password.toString());
    mref = new Firebase("https://encryptlogin.firebaseio.com/");
  createNewAccount(email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());

}
    private void createNewAccount(String email, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createNewAccount:" + email);
    if (!validateForm()) {
        return;
    }
    //This method sets up a new User by fetching the user entered details.
    setUpUser();
    //This method  method  takes in an email address and password, validates them and then creates a new user
    // with the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method.
    // If the new account was created, the user is also signed in, and the AuthStateListener runs the onAuthStateChanged callback.
    // In the callback, you can use the getCurrentUser method to get the user's account data.

    showProgressDialog();
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {



                 Log.d(TAG, "Register Successfully " + task.isSuccessful());
                    hideProgressDialog();

      // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
          // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.

     if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
     Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration failed.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        hideProgressDialog();

                    } else {
        onAuthenticationSuccess(task.getResult().getUser());
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Register Successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } hideProgressDialog();
                }
            });
}
    private void onAuthenticationSuccess(FirebaseUser mUser) {
    // Write new user
    saveNewUser(mUser.getUid(),  user.getName(),user.getPhoneNumber(), user.getEmail(), user.getPassword()); 
    signOut();
    // Go to LoginActivity
    Intent i =new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
private void saveNewUser(String userId, String name, String phone, String               email, String password) {

    User user = new User(userId,name,phone,email,password);
    mref.child("Users").child(name).setValue(user);
}
private void signOut() {
    mAuth.signOut();
}
//This method, validates email address and password
private boolean validateForm() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String userEmail = email.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail)) {
        email.setError("Required.");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        email.setError(null);
    }

    String userPassword = password.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userPassword)) {
        password.setError("Required.");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        password.setError(null);
    }

    String userPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userPhoneNumber)){
        phoneNumber.setError("Required");
        valid = false;
    }else {
        phoneNumber.setError(null);
    }

    String userAddress = address.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userAddress)){
        address.setError("Required");
        valid = false;
    }else {
        address.setError(null);
    }
    if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(userEmail).matches()){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"please enter valid email",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (userEmail.isEmpty() && userPassword.isEmpty()userAddress.isEmpty()
    && userPhoneNumber.isEmpty()){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"all fields are mandatory",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return valid;
}
public void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

public void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
    public void encryption(String pass){
    String seedValue = "secKey";
    try {
        password.setText(AESHelper.encrypt(seedValue,pass));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}  
}
```

**Login Activity**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


EditText Email, pwd;
Button login;
TextView Register,Forgetpwd;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Forget_password.class));
        finish();
    }

    Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEmail);
    pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);
    Register = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register);
    Forgetpwd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reset);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
        }
    });

    Forgetpwd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Forget_password.class));
        }
    });

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String email = Email.getText().toString();
            final String password = pwd.getText().toString();


            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"please enter valid email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if (email.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"all fields are mandatory",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            showProgressDialog();
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                          /*  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // there was an error
                                if (password.length() < 6) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "minimum password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                    }
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Forget_password.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                            hideProgressDialog();
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}

private void showProgressDialog() {

    if (progressDialog == null) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    progressDialog.show();
}

public void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}    
 }
```

**AESHelper Class**

```
  import javax.crypto.Cipher;
  import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
  import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
  import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

  public class AESHelper {
  public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext 
     throwsException{

    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
    return toHex(result);
   }

      public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) 
     throwsException{
       byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
       byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
       byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
       return new String(result);
   }
    private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG","Crypto");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
  }
    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception{ 
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}
   private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted)throws
   Exception{
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
   }
  public static String toHex(String txt) {
    return toHex(txt.getBytes());
   }
    public static String fromHex(String hex) {
    return new String(toByte(hex));
   }

    public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length()/2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).
    byteValue();
    return result;
  }
    public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null)
        return "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
   }
     private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
     private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
  }
  }
```

what do I do to match password at login activity. help me plz...

Comment: **Don't encrypt passwords**.  Hash them.  Use a password hash like bcrypt or the key deriviation function PBKDF2.  Encrypting passwords **leads to direct security issues**, do not do it.

Comment: In your code, you used firebase authentication for login using email and password. Then Why do you need to store the password in the user object? Firebase Auth stores it for you.